# grid cant load data and page navigation not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, jqgrid

Grid cant load data from servlete and page navigation not work but when make "loadonce:false" grid load but not page navigation wrok -

```
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                url:'JQGridServlet?action=fetchData',
               datatype: "xml",
                height: 550 ,    
                width:840,                                                      //    'B2C'           'AD''AC'                   
                colNames:['srNo','DNO','C_Id','Customer_Name','FR','PA','mty','Act','Location','Detail_Address'],
                colModel:[
                           // {name:'act1',index:'act1', width:20,sortable:false},
                          {name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true,editable:false,hidden:true},
                          // {name:'delboy',index:'delboy', width:35,sortable:true,editable:false},
                          {name:'DNO',index:'DNO', width:33,sortable:true,editable:false,editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },focus:false},

                          {name:'FR',index:'FR', width:25,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{number:true}},
                          {name:'PA',index:'PA', width:25,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{edithidden:true,number:true}},
                          {name:'mty',index:'mty', width:25,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{edithidden:true,number:true}},
                          {name:'act',index:'act', width:13,sortable:false},
                          {name:'Location',index:'Location', width:50,sortable:false},
                       {name:'Detail_Address',index:'Detail_Address',width:150,sortable:false
                            }
                        ],
                  paging: true,
                  rowNum:50,
                  rowList:[50,100,150],
                  pager: $("#page"),
                  sortname: 'DNO',
                  sortorder: 'asc',
                  sortable: true, 
                  footerrow: true,
                  userDataOnFooter: true,
                  //loadonce:true,
                  viewrecords:true,
                  gridview: true,
                  altRows : true,
                 onSelectRow : function(id)
                {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) 
                    {
                       // alert(parseInt(id)+1);
                        DNO = $('#list').getCell(id,'DNO');
                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{editurl: 'JQGridServlet?action=Edit&DNO='+DNO});
                        jQuery('#list').saveRow(lastsel, true, 'clientArray');
                        jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true, null, null);
                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                        lastsel = id;
                      } 
                },
//MY servelet code:

if (request.getParameter("action").equals("fetchData")) 
                    {
                         System.out.println("in fetchData");
                    }
```

but not go in side that action when "loadonce:true".
please any body suggest to how to solve this problem.

Comment: where is the `url` value??

Comment: can you share your complete jqgrid code?

Comment: hey I am try with "loadonce:false" grid load but page navigation still not work,so what to do?

Comment: you know what would be nice? Complete code so that we can understand what exactly is happening. A random piece of code won't help you or us here.

Comment: so I have send more code, now please check it and try to solve my problem

Comment: @AloNE post your servlet code also

Comment: @AloNE: You can post exact XML response returned from the server instead of posting servlet code. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), Developer Tools of IE (press F12) or Chrome or other tools to catch HTTP traffic. One can save XML response in file and debug your JavaScript code without having server code working.